# Why doesn't this CSS style my elements correctly?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I'm trying to have an inline-block navigation bar. When someone hovers over the li, I want it to change background colors - simple enough.

It appears as though my code causes the background to be off about 2 inches.

Here is the offending code -

css-

```
#mainNav {
    width: 100%;
    background:#bbb;
    border-right: 2px solid #777;
    border-left: 2px solid #777;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #555;
}

#mainNav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    border-right: 2px solid #777;
}

#mainNav ul li.active {
    background:#aaa;
}

#mainNav ul li:hover {
    background:#aaa;
}
```

html-

```
<div class='container_12'>
    <nav id="mainNav">
        <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Games</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Forums</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Screenshot:
[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `margin-left` to `li` will solve the problem.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wejSJ/1/)

Comment: Works, however it pulls the first LI out of the list -- anything else that can be done?

Comment: @JacobAndersen yes there's always a solution , you can use `#mainNav ul li:first-child { margin-left:0px; }`

Comment: @JacobAndersen for more selector see http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild

Comment: Wonderful. Works and looks great. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

It should also be :

`#mainNav ul li:active {
    background:#aaa;
}`

Just like hover is coded out. Still not sure about the original question though.